# How to check if a button was pressed using the keyboard module?

Tags: python, keyboard

I made an auto-jump program and I want it to stop when I press "q". For some reason the program just stops when it reaches the "if" line.

```
import keyboard as kbd
from time import sleep
while True:
    kbd.press("space")
    sleep(0.1)
    kbd.release("space")            
    if kbd.read_key() == "q":
        break
```

I tried making this programm using different keyboard libraries, but it didn't help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [docs](https://github.com/boppreh/keyboard#keyboard.read_key)

> keyboard.read_key(suppress=False)
>
> Blocks until a keyboard event happens, then returns that event's name or, if missing, its scan code.

That's why your code stops at `read_key` function call - the function is blocking.

What you want instead is to asynchronously get notified about key being pressed. You can use [add_hotkey](https://github.com/boppreh/keyboard#keyboardadd_hotkeyhotkey-callback-args-suppressfalse-timeout1-trigger_on_releasefalse) for this purpose. Set up a callback that will allow you to break out of the loop. If you want to trigger the callback once remember to remove the hotkey.

How I see it (I didn't test this code):

```py
was_q_pressed = False
q_hotkey = None

def on_q_press():
  global was_q_pressed
  was_q_pressed = True
  kbd.remove_hotkey(q_hotkey)


q_hotkey = kbd.add_hotkey("q", on_q_press)

while True:
    kbd.press("space")
    sleep(0.1)
    kbd.release("space")            
    if was_q_pressed:
        break
```

Comment: Thank you! It helped me a lot, but only thing you forgot to put in your code is "global was_q_pressed" in function.